# Mount encrypted folder on synology nas via terminal

Tags: terminal, mount, nas, synology, ecryptfs

I was searching for a solution to mount an encrypted folder on my synology nas via terminal and found out that DSM uses ecryptfs. Using `mount.ecryptfs $ENCRYPT_DIR_PATH $MOUNTED_DIR_PATH` actually works but the mounted directory with decrypted data doesn't show in the samba shares or in the web GUI. Further i found out that synology made a program/script to solve this. `synoshare --enc_mount $ENCRYPT_DIR_PATH $PASSWORD` should mount the folder and make it visible but sadly it crashes.

```
Error SYNOShareEncShareMount() failed.[0x1400 share_db_get.c:31]
```

Does anyone know what the problem is here?

---

**SECURITY WARNING:**

Someone who searches a way to do this might stumble upon this thread, so i want to warn you about something i read [here](https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=107091). If you use `synoshare --enc_mount $ENCRYPT_DIR_PATH $PASSWORD` your password will be in plain text on the terminal and also in `/var/log/bash_history.log` which is obviously a security flaw. If you scroll down on the linked page you find a post from user *fairlane* in which he wrote a small script to use `synoshare` without revealing the password. For the sake of completeness i post it here.

```
echo -n "Enter Share Password: "
read -s passwordVariable
echo ""
/usr/syno/sbin/synoshare --enc_mount $1 $passwordVariable
```

Comment: I think you should add to the security warning section that the password you provide with this solution will still be visible in /var/log/auth.log. So anyone with root access to the system will be able to also find your encryption password(s). Now, one could of course in a normal home environment assume that strangers do not have root and it would be good enough.  

A persistent person with physical access may be able to extract /var/log/auth.log from the system, rendering the encryption useless.

Comment: You can avoid the `auth.log` entry by making sudo run bash and providing the command on stdin, eg:  `sudo bash <<<"synoshare --enc_mount $DIR $PW"`  (note `<<<` in bash means provide the string on stdin).

Comment: It looks like Synology forums have moved, and they never made it to archive.org. The original post might be at https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/17/post/89231?reply=305243 now, although it's probably lost some linebreaks.

Comment: @mabahj As far as I can tell, auth.log only logs commands triggered directly by `sudo`.  So you possibly only need the `<<<` trick if you're literally running `sudo synoshare ...`.  If you're running `sudo myscript` and `myscript` calls `synoshare ...`, it's probably fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. Instead of using `synoshare --enc_mount $ENCRYPT_DIR_PATH $PASSWORD` you use it like `synoshare --enc_mount $SHARE_NAME $PASSWORD`. So you have to put the actual name of the share using " " as argument instead of the concrete path.

Comment: it works but the mounted shared folder is not visible in  "File Station" and in Control Panel -> Shared Folders. How can one notice them that the folder is mounted?